# PHP rand but with a bigger chance of getting another number?

Tags: php, random, numbers, generator

I have a php file where i want to get a random number, but i want it to be a 80% chance to be 1. And then 20% to be either 2, 3 or 4. Usually you can do something like this:

```
rand(1, 4)
```

But i want to have a higher chance of getting `1`,  as i explained.

Answer (score 10):

You can use another rand :

```
$rand = rand(1, 10);

if ($rand <= 8)
  $value = 1;
else
  $value = rand(2,4);
```

Answer (score 5):

Generate a number in [-10, 4] and transform:

```
$value = max(1, rand(-10, 4))
```

This will have the correct distribution and ought to perform well. It's not as tractable as a solution involving two draws but it will be faster.

Comment: I came out with this: `$value = abs(rand(-10, 4));`

Answer (score 1):

Though the answers provided by @Bathsheba and @djidi are the best. Here is a different approach.
Since the `1` part should 80% and the `2,3,4` should be 20%, we multiply the number of random numbers generated so that 3 numbers equal 20% (ending up with 15 in this case):

```
<?php

$random = rand(1,15);

$result = 0;
switch($random) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        $result = $random;
        break;
    default:
        $result = 1;
}

echo $result;
```

Chance to get 1 = 12/15 = 0.8
Chance to get either 2, 3 or 4 = 1/15 = 0.066666666667

In Bathsheba's answer:
Chance to get 1 = 12 * 1/15 = 12/15 = 0.8 (since there are 15 numbers between -10 and 4)
Chance to get either 2, 3 or 4 = 1/15 = 0.066666666667 (since only 3 numbers survive the `max()` unaltered)

In Djidi's answer:
Chance to get 1 = 8/10 = 0.8
Chance to get either 2, 3 or 4 = 2/10 * 1/3 = 2/30 = 1/15 = 0.066666666667

Math stays the same =)